# Анализ данных Excel. Сравнение дат и выявление самой поздней по каждому клиенту

Tags: excel, vba

Ломаю голову уже несколько дней.

Есть БД в excel с большим количеством столбцов и +- 45000 строк.
Это все список заказов, который нужно проанализировать.

Каждая строка - это заказ, в строке указаны данные клиента и статистика (некорректная)
Нужно проанализировать БД и выявить по каждому клиенту самую позднюю дату создания заказа и выдачи заказа и записать в отдельное поле, которое следующим этапам буду выгружать в CRM и строить алгоритмы на этих данных.

Понятно, что заказов много и у каждого клиента их разное количество, а выгружать нужно только по одной строке на каждого клиента.
т.е. 1 клиент, 5 заказов (5 строк) - ищем самый поздний заказ, берем оттуда дату и суммируем цену всех заказов. и вот такое нужно получить уже в 1 строке (4 остальные удалить)

При этом есть ряд других полей, которые нужно заполнить по самому свежему заказу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Анализ данных - задача для СУБД, а не для табличного процессора. Выгрузи всю таблицу. А там получить одну запись на клиента, тем более по столь тривиальному критерию - секундное дело.

Comment: Как это было давно) Я вижу, что excel с трудом прям вытягивает загрузку такого массива, не говорю уже про какаю-то работу там. Пробовал чет и в Power Qwery, чет не моуг понять с какой стороны подойти, никогда не работал в MS базах. MySQL помню еле-еле, только название, видимо. Может посоветуете какие-то сервисы простые, куда загружаешь и просто анализируешь без знаний особенных?

Comment: 45K строк - это немного... Другое дело, если там столбцов куча-мала ) VBA может с задачей справиться, но такая обработка выходит за пределы простой помощи.

Answer (score 1):

На первый взгляд, задача легко решается с помощью сводной таблицы. Клиентов поместите в строки, а в данные максимум по полю дата.